# Angular js remove only last dynamic text field

Tags: angularjs, api, kendo-ui

When I remove text field, just remove only last text field.What the logic behind that. I can't understand properly whats going on in here. I am also new in angular js. This is my js code-

```
function ItemController($q, $scope, $http) {

var item_id = document.getElementsByName('item_id')[0].value;

$http
    .get("http://localhost:8000/api/product-track/get-product-phase-item/" + item_id, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined, 'Process-Data': false}
    })
    .then(function(response){

        data = response.data.item_category;
        $scope.items = response.data.data;

    });

$http
    .get("http://localhost:8000/api/product-track/get-product-phase-item/" + item_id, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined,
            'Process-Data': false
        }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        data = response.data.item_category;
        $scope.items = response.data.data;
        $scope.fullArr = []
        var i = 0;
        var a = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {

            $('#item_category_id_' + i++).kendoDropDownList({
                optionLabel: "Select Category",
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                dataSource: data,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                index: 0
            })

            var dropdownlist = $("#item_category_id_" + a++).data("kendoDropDownList");
            dropdownlist.value(item.item_category_id);

            $scope.fullArr.push($http
                .get("http://localhost:8000/api/item/get-item-name/" + item.item_category_id, {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': undefined,
                        'Process-Data': false
                    }
                }));
        });
        sendReq()
    });

function sendReq() {
    var i = 0;
    var a = 0
    var b = 0;
    $q.all($scope.fullArr).then(function(response) {
        angular.forEach(response, function(item) {
            data = item.data;
            var item_id = $scope.items[b++].item_id;
            $('#item_id_' + i++).kendoDropDownList({
                optionLabel: "Select Item",
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                dataSource: data,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                index: 0
            });

            var dropdownlist = $("#item_id_" + a++).data("kendoDropDownList");
            dropdownlist.value(item_id);

        });
    });
}

$scope.Append = function() {
    $scope.items.push($scope.items.length);
    console.log($scope.items);

    var i = $scope.items.length - 1 ;
    console.log(i);

    $http
        .get("http://localhost:8000/api/item/get-item-category-name", {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined, 'Process-Data': false}
        })
        .then(function(response){
            data = response.data;


            $('#item_category_id_' +i).kendoDropDownList({
                optionLabel   : "Select Category",
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                dataSource: data,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                index: 0
            });

            $('#item_id_' + i).kendoDropDownList({
                optionLabel   : "Select Item"

            });

        });
}

$scope.Remove = function(index) {
    console.log(index);
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    console.log($scope.items);
}

$scope.getItem = function (index) {

    var value = $("#item_category_id_" + index).data("kendoDropDownList").value();

    $http
        .get("http://localhost:8000/api/item/get-item-name/" + value, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined, 'Process-Data': false}
        })
        .then(function(response){
            data = response.data;
            $('#item_id_' + index).kendoDropDownList({
                optionLabel   : "Select Item",
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                dataSource: data,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                index: 0
            });

        });
}
```

}

This is my html code-

```
<div class="uk-grid uk-margin-large-top uk-margin-large-bottom" data-uk-grid-margin>
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-1">
    <table class="uk-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="uk-text-nowrap">Item Category</th>
                <th class="uk-text-nowrap">Item </th>
                <th class="uk-text-nowrap">Quantity</th>
                <th class="uk-text-nowrap">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="form_section" id="data_clone" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
            <td>
                <select id="item_category_id_@{{ $index }}" name="item_category_id[@{{ $index }}]" ng-model="item_category_id" ng-change="getItem($index)" required>


                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select title="Select Item" id="item_id_@{{ $index }}" name="item_id[@{{ $index }}]" required>


                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="md-input" placeholder="Enter Quantity" value="@{{ item.total }}" name="total[@{{ $index }}]" required />
            </td>
            <td class="uk-text-right uk-text-middle">
                    <span class="uk-input-group-addon">
                        <a ng-click="Remove($index)"><i class="material-icons">&#xE15C;</i></a>
                    </span>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-bottom: 0px;" class="form_section" id="data_clone">
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td class="uk-text-right uk-text-middle">
                    <span class="uk-input-group-addon">
                    <a ng-click="Append()"><i class="material-icons">&#xE147;</i></a></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

[my ui looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDUFd.png)

Sorry that, I can't elaborate my problem as a new that you are expected. 
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question properly(correct me if I'm wrong) then I guess you would like to understand how clicking the delete button actually deletes a particular row.

Let me explain:

There is a delete button at the end of every row, the code is:

```
<span class="uk-input-group-addon">
    <a ng-click="Remove($index)"><i class="material-icons">&#xE15C;</i></a>
</span>
```

In above code there is a click handler `ng-click="Remove($index)"`, so when you click on the delete button it will call a function passing in the index of the current item. The function is exposed via. the model and in your case that would be `$scope.Remove` function. The definition looks like:

```
$scope.Remove = function(index) {
    // .......
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1); //<-- This is the code that deletes the item from the array.
    // ........
}
```

In the above function, we call the `Array.splice` method on the array and that updates the array. For more info read [splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp).

And since the array is displayed using `ng-repeat`, it would automatically detect the changes to the array and will also update the view.
For more info please read [AngularJS ng-repeat directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Here your code is using `ng-repeat` directive to display the rows, like:

```
<tr class="form_section" id="data_clone" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
.....
.....
</tr>
```

The update happens due to the so-called AngularJS 2-way binding. Please read [this article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html) for more info.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: My code is exactly same as you told. But not working. Only last element is removed. :(

Comment: Thanks for reply... :)

Comment: Can you tell me what is the expected behaviour? The code is coded to remove the last element. So, I'm confused when you say that it is not working?

Comment: When i am  trying to remove 2nd or 3rd element, its remove only last element that i don't expect.When i want to remove 1st 2nd or 3rd element, code should remove that element but it's not. Remove only last element for every click that i don't want.

Comment: Can you provide a working code snippet? I can't see why it will not delete the row on which you clicked the delete button. Let me correct my previous statement: The code is written to delete a particular row and not to delete the last row based on the index.

Comment: Here is a quick demo, I've tried to use the same structure as in your code.
http://codepen.io/gauravmahto/pen/ZeooPV?editors=1010 . Here everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine. You aren't using any filter too. ([further read](https://codeutopia.net/blog/2014/11/10/angularjs-best-practices-avoid-using-ng-repeats-index/) for filter issue)

This is inconsistent behavior\issue. Use of `track by $id(item)` and further change in method `Remove(item)` should be required.
[See This](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7119) might help you